# remove query parameter from router after push, prepare for next call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have mutliple actions passing an `objectId` which is used to navigate using the vue router.
Some actions pass additional parameters like `mode=alternate` which we need to pass on.
There might also be other query-parameters around like `locale` so don't want to replace the complete query of the router, only set the id and additinal paramters to the existing query.
Now after `router.push` is done is it possible to remove the additional paramters for future calls, the problem is that parameters like `mode=alternate` will be passed to the next calls.

`openObject("ID1", {mode: "alternate"})` results in */object?id=ID1&mode=alternate*

the next call

`openObject("ID2", {})` results in */object?id=ID2&mode=alternate*

but should be */object?id=ID*

```
openObject(objectId: string, parameters?: {[key: string]: string;},): void {
    const query = { ...parameters, id: objectId };
    this.router.push({
      path: "/object",
      query: Object.assign({}, this.router.currentRoute.value.query, query),
    });
    
    // TODO: Remove 'parameters' from router so they not part of the next call (without page refresh)
}
```

There might also be other parameters than `mode`, so I can't just remove that one.

Currentyl I'm doing this before the actual `router.push()`, but I think there must be a better solution:

```
const storageKey = "tempParameter";
const tempParameter = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
if (tempParameter) {
  tempParameter
    .split(",")
    .forEach(
      (element) => delete this.router.currentRoute.value.query[element],
    );
  localStorage.removeItem(storageKey);
}
// if additinal parameters are set, add keys to temp storage to remove in next call
if (parameters && Object.keys(parameters).length !== 0) {
  localStorage.setItem(storageKey, Object.keys(parameters).toString());
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce. This is not what is expected. You're not removing `mode` from `this.router.currentRoute.value.query`. In case the problem is specific to this code, that's the problem here